# Unity Normalized Movement Extremely Slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

As said in the title, when I normalize my movement (to prevent diagonal from having increased magnitude) my movement speed is extremely slow even when increasing it drastically. I feel like it has to do with *when* the normalize is being applied but I'm not sure.

```cs
        float targetMovingSpeed = IsRunning ? runSpeed : speed;

        // Get targetVelocity from input.
        Vector2 targetVelocity = new Vector2( Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * targetMovingSpeed, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * targetMovingSpeed);

        if (targetVelocity.magnitude > 1)
        {
            targetVelocity = targetVelocity.normalized;
        }

        // Apply movement.
        rigidbody.velocity = transform.rotation * new Vector3(targetVelocity.x, rigidbody.velocity.y, targetVelocity.y);
```

Comment: because you multiply the movement speed before you normalised it.. do it the other way round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You multiply the input by `targetMovingSpeed`, then you normalize it which will make its magnitude to be `1`.

You rather want to do it like

```
// see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.ClampMagnitude.html
var input = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical")), 1f);
var targetVelocity = input * targetMovingSpeed;

rigidbody.velocity = transform.rotation * targetVelocity;
```